# Generic types and polymorphism in interfaces

Tags: java, generics, polymorphism, mybatis

I'm trying to generify some calls to DB using MyBatis, but I've hit a wall so far.

Let's say I have this entities and mappers:

```
public interface Entity {

    <T extends Entity> Class<Insertable<T>> mapper();
}

public interface Insertable<T extends Entity> {

    void insert(T entity);
}

public interface ClientMapper extends Insertable<Client> {

    void insert(Client client);
}

public interface CampaignMapper extends Insertable<Campaign> {

    void insert(Campaign campaign);
}

public class Client implements Entity {

    private final Long id;

    public Client(final Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public <T extends Entity> Class<Insertable<T>> mapper() {
        return ClientMapper.class; // Incompatible types error
    }
```

I'm getting this compilation error even though `ClientMapper` is of type `Insertable<Client>`, being `Client` a type of `Entity`.

The objective is getting to the following type-safe code:

```
public class MapperOperation {

    public static void insert(Entity entity) {
        insert(entity, entity.mapper());
    }

    private static <V extends Entity, K extends Insertable<V>> void insert(V entity, Class<K> mapperClass) {
        try (SqlSession session = PersistenceManager.get().openSession()) {
            K mapper = session.getMapper(mapperClass);
            mapper.insert(entity);
            session.commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Could not insert entity {}", entity, e);
        }
    }
}
```

This way, I can just call the method `insert` with an instance of any `Entity` and then ask him to give me his `mapper` so that I can insert it.

Is this possible? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I have a "off topic" question: What do interfaces `ClientMapper` and `CampaignMapper` do? I mean they just re-declare the insert method, with the same signature...

Comment: It's how Mybatis works (as far as I know). Each interface has an XML associated with the query that's gonna be executed. You then get an instance of that interface (mapper) using the session and when you call the method, Mybatis does the magic.

Answer (score 4):

It should compile with these changes:

```
public interface Entity {
    <T extends Entity> Class<? extends Insertable<T>> mapper();
}    

// ...

public <T extends Entity> Class<? extends Insertable<T>> mapper() {
    return ClientMapper.class;
}
```

You cannot assign `Class<ClientMapper>` to `Class<Insertable<T>>`, for the same reason you cannot assign `List<Integer>` to `List<Number>`.

If you could, it would be unsafe:

```
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<>();
List<Number> ln = li; // does not compile
ln.add(3.14);
Integer i = li.get(0); // it's a Double!
```

**EDIT:** This is not the only issue: the method returns something which depends on `T`, but you return another one. The problem can be simplified:

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C extends A {}

<T extends A> T getValue() {
    return new C();
}
```

Here, `T` might be resolved to any subtype of `A`, so we cannot return an instance of `C` because `T` might be resolved to `B` (e.g. by calling `this.<B>getValue()`), and `C` is not a subtype of `B`.

Comment: It still gives me the same error `incompatible types: java.lang.Class<ClientMapper> cannot be converted to java.lang.Class<? extends Insertable<T>>`

Comment: Yes, this was not the only problem. I edited my answer.

Comment: I think I see the problem. Guess there's no workaround then, right? Ultimately, what I want to accomplish is that the call `insert(entity, entity.mapper())` is type-safe.